# rsyslog && sending data to other host

Tags: rsyslog, logger

Using **CentOS** 6.4.

Problem is - that messages from `kern.*` facility doesn't appear on other server.

Tring to send data:

```
# logger -p kern.warning -t TEST "Test warning for remote host KERNEL"
# logger -p cron.warning -t TEST "Test warning for remote host CRON"
# logger -p mail.warning -t TEST "Test warning for remote host MAIL"
```

Checking **MySQL** data:

```
mysql> select ID,Message from SystemEvents order by ID desc limit 3;
+--------+------------------------------------+
| ID     | Message                            |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| 524007 |  Test warning for remote host MAIL |
| 524006 |  Test warning for remote host CRON |
| 524005 |  Test warning for remote host MAIL |
+--------+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is no data from `kern` facility. Why?

Config on host-recipient:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf | egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|#'
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$ModLoad imtcp
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
kern.*                                                 /var/log/kern.log
syslog.*                                                /var/log/syslog.log
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local0.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 *
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

**MySQL** config on recipient:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/hostname.conf
$ModLoad ommysql
:fromhost, isequal, "hostname" :ommysql:localhost,Syslog,rsyslog,megapass
```

And host-sender:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf | egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|#'
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
kern.*                                                  @hostname
syslog.*                                                /var/log/syslog.log
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
mail.*                                                  @hostname
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
cron.*                                                  @hostname
*.emerg                                                 *
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
local4.*                                                /var/log/ldap.log
```

**UPD**

Also, I noticed that data doesn't send even to local file:

```
kern.*                                                  /var/log/kern.log
```

And:

```
# logger -p kern.warning -t TEST "Test warning for local host KERNEL"
```

And:

```
# tail /var/log/kern.log | grep "TEST"
```

Return nothing.

So - am I correct if I guess that `logger`can't send data "from kernel"? It's sounds logical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From logger man page on facility names:

```
kern       cannot be generated from user process
```

Source here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html

Comment: Thanks :-) I even forgot about this issue, but this answer helpfull.